# MUI DataGrid action action button group don't change

Tags: reactjs, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

In my MUI DataGrid Pro I have two action buttons in every row they should change depending  wether the row is in edit or view mode. I copied the demo code from MUI and I adapted it to add the row to my database.

Everything works well and the row is added to the database but the buttons change back to the view mode for a split second an then they are back in the edit mode.

The onProcessRowUpdateError returns this.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
at getRowIdFromRowModel (gridRowsUtils.js:30:1)
at gridRowsUtils.js:154:1
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at updateCacheWithNewRows (gridRowsUtils.js:153:1)
at useGridRows.js:118:1
at Proxy.updateRows (useGridApiMethod.js:14:1)
at useGridRowEditing.js:390:1
```

[image]

column definition:

```
const actionColumns = [
        {
            field: 'actions',
            type: 'actions',
            headerName: 'Actions',
            width: 100,
            cellClassName: 'actions',
            getActions: ({ id }) =>
            {
                const isInEditMode = rowModesModel[id]?.mode === GridRowModes.Edit;

                if (isInEditMode)
                {
                    return [
                        <GridActionsCellItem
                            icon={<SaveIcon />}
                            label="Save"
                            sx={{
                                color: 'secondary.main',
                            }}
                            onClick={handleSaveClick(id)}

                        />,
                        <GridActionsCellItem
                            icon={<CancelIcon />}
                            label="Cancel"
                            onClick={handleCancelClick(id)}
                            color="white"
                        />,
                    ];
                }

                return [
                    <GridActionsCellItem
                        icon={<EditIcon />}
                        label="Edit"
                        onClick={handleEditClick(id)}
                        color="white"
                    />,
                    < GridActionsCellItem
                        icon={<DeleteIcon />}
                        label="Delete"
                        onClick={handleDeleteClick(id)}
                        color="white"
                    />,
                ];
            },
        },]
```

Clicking the add button

```
    {
        // Create a new row object with a unique ID and default property values
        const id = uuidv4();
        const newRow = { id, reg_name: "", reg_created: '', isNew: true };
        setRegions(oldRegions => [newRow, ...oldRegions]);
        setRowModesModel((oldModel) => ({
            ...oldModel,
            [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit, fieldToFocus: 'reg_name' },
        }));
        setIsNewRow(true)
    }
```

Click the save button

```
const handleSaveClick = (id) => async () =>
    {
        console.log('save click')
        setCurrentId(id);
        setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View } });
    };
```

Triggers the process row update

```
async function processRowUpdate(newRow) 
    {
        console.log('process row update')
        const updatedRow = { ...newRow, isNew: false };
        if (rows)
        {
            setRows(rows.map((row) => (row.id === newRow.id ? updatedRow : row)));
        }
        // New record
        if (updatedRow, isNewRow)
        {
            console.log('add new region')
            const regName = updatedRow.reg_name
            try
            {
                const data = await APIServiceRegions.addRegion({ regName })
            }
            catch (error)
            {
                console.error(error);
            }
            setIsNewRow(false)
        }
        // Edited record
        if (updatedRow, isEditedRow)
        {
            console.log('edit region')
            const regName = updatedRow.reg_name
            try
            {
                const data = await APIServiceRegions.updateRegion({ currentId, regName })
            }
            catch (error)
            {
                console.error(error);
            }
            setIsEditedRow(false)
        }

    };
```

Sets the rowModes

```
const handleRowModesModelChange = (newRowModesModel) =>
    {
        console.log('handle row modes model change')

        setRowModesModel(newRowModesModel);

    };
```

This is the component view

```
<DataGridPro
                    sx={{
                        borderColor: 'white',
                        '.MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders': {
                            borderBottom: 'solid',
                            borderBottomColor: 'white'
                        },
                    }}
                    rows={regions}
                    key={regions.id}
                    columns={[
                        ...RegionsColumns, ...actionColumns

                    ]}
                    editMode="row"
                    initialState={{
                        ...RegionsColumns.initialState,
                        columns: {
                            ...RegionsColumns.initialState?.columns,
                            columnVisibilityModel: {
                                reg_id: false,
                            }
                        }
                    }}
                    slotProps={{
                        toolbar: { setRows, setRowModesModel },
                    }}
                    onRowSelectionModelChange={handleSelectionModelChange}
                    rowSelectionModel={selectionModel}
                    rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
                    onRowModesModelChange={handleRowModesModelChange}
                    onRowEditStop={handleRowEditStop}
                    processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
                    onProcessRowUpdateError={(error) => console.log(error)}
                    hideFooter={true}
                />
```